# How to Restore Default Settings for Virtual Machine Network Adapter in Azure manage console

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine

How to Restore Default Settings for Virtual Machine Network Adapter in Azure manage console. I cannot connect the vm desktop remotely after I changed the Ip Address in Virtual Machine Network Adapter. then I restarted the vm in the manage console, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually [reset the network interface for Azure Windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/reset-network-interface) to resolve issues when you cannot connect to Microsoft Azure Windows Virtual Machine (VM) after you disabled the default NIC or manually set a static IP for the NIC.

[image]

You could follow the above steps to reset the NIC. This works for me. Just a reminder, you need to re-RDP to the VM until the VM status is restored **running**. If it takes a long time, you could try to refresh the portal.
[image]

Let me know if this works on your side.